# Difference between adding a onClick listerner via Jquery and via a html onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <title>
        HelloWorld JQuery   
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    Lets play around with JQuery
</p>
</body>

<script >

    function changeColorOnClick()
    {
        console.log("changed color");
    }
    var pTag=$('p');
    pTag.on('click',changeColorOnClick);
</script>
</html>
```

The  event  listener works fine ,but when I inspect element in my browser the `p` tag has no associated `onClick` attribute , why is that?
Ain't it the same whether we bind a listener via a script or mention the handler method in the html element tag itself?

Answer (score 0):

When you attach event handler to an element via `document.getElementById('myElement').onclick` or `$('#myElement').on(...)`, it doesn't set or change the `onClick` attribute of the element. It just attaches internal handler.

To change the `onClick` attribute of the element one must use `$(elem).attr('onClick','click_handler_func');`. Then this attribute will be shown in the DOM inspector.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things wrong I see.

1. It's best to bind the function in a document.ready call; then it's only bound once the DOM is completely ready
2. Use a closure when binding.

This should do it:

```
function changeColorOnClick()
{
    console.log("changed color");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var pTag=$('p');
    pTag.on('click',function(){changeColorOnClick();});
});
```